# How ASP connects to SQL

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I don't program in ASP at all, but I'm trying to figure out how a particular asp app connects to a database. the database username/password/server aren't stored in the source itself, it's not stored in the one #include, and it's not stored in global.asp. is there another way? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably using [integrated authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication) which uses the windows account the process is executing under. In development this would be your account.

Comment: The server name would still have to be stored somewhere, but it could be just `.`, so it would be easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly using a DSN connection